# How can I set terminal-local options in neovim?

Tags: neovim

I found that if I run `:set nonumber` in terminal buffer, the option only applies to that terminal buffer, not window I run the command.
Neovim's help doc says that `'number'` is a window-local option, But it doesn't seem right when dealing with terminal buffers.

Is the option `'number'` can be treated as buffer-local option or terminal-local option?

If so, how can I set terminal-local options?

Comment: There is no such thing as terminal local option.

Comment: You set window local option of a window that was displaying the terminal buffer, so the terminal now has line numbers. What's the problem? Isn't that working as intended? What's your goal?